# What's the best way to check proxy in C++?

Tags: c++, proxy

The perfect way would be a library, where I could simply pass the adress and it would be checked. However, in case there's none (which I think is unlikely) I could write my own.

However, I don't know exactly what's the best way to do it. What url I should call? Or is proxy such thing that with a specific request you should be able to get its response? If I had to call url, Google is always up but calling its homepage would take a lot of bandwidth. The best checker know to me is http://www.project2025.com/charon.php (Charon). Does anyone know how it exactly checks proxies?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking.  Are you asking if an http proxy is installed on the host OS?  Unfortunately, such a check would likely be very OS dependent.

Comment: What I mean is, lets say you have a list of 1000 proxies. I want to check proxy for reliability, that it works.

Answer (score 0):

Last few days, I use a new software called 'proxyabuse' ([www.proxyabuse.com](http://www.proxyabuse.com)) and it check perfectly many options for proxies... Look it

Comment: Thanks, but I don't need proxies myself. However, I'll need a proxy checker in my software solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can read online proxy standardized protocols (RFCS) and use them to create a working socket tcp checker.

[SOCKS5 RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1928)

[SOCKS4 RFC](https://github.com/h12w/socks/blob/master/spec/SOCKS4.protocol.txt)

Or you can also use online proxy checker to do your thing fast like :

[1 proxy checker](https://checkerproxy.net/)

[2 proxy checker](https://www.proxychecker.ai/proxy-checker)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34386861)

Answer (score -1):

After some research, I've found out how the Charon works. It actually opens port 80 in local machine and serves the php script which simply tells

```
REMOTE_ADDR = {the IP address}
```

If the IP matches the proxy which request is made from, proxy is anonymous, however, if it shows your actual IP, proxy is transparent. That's about it.